# Multi user mac and iCloud data security

Tags: icloud, security, privacy

I'm currently using a shared Mac with other users.
All user accounts are Administrators.
I noticed that with sudo my files are accessible from other user, and I'm wondering if also my iCloud Data (Notes, app data ecc. ) are accessible and readable in the same way.

Did someone has any clue?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

An "Administrator" account has complete access to all other accounts through tools such as "sudo". To the extent that iCloud data is unsecured in the user accounts, it could be accessed by anyone with an administrator account. However, without the user's login password, access to information stored in the login keychain is not possible - so passwords to servers and websites and the like are reasonably "safe".

The simplest way to give reasonable secuity is to not make everyone an administrator - the standard setup requires administrator privledges to view files stored in other login account folders, so non-administrator accounts cannot view such files. If using non-administrator accounts is not feasable, one could create encrypted files and/or disk images to store private things.

The FileVault whole disk encryption does not do what you want, since it still allows full disk access to any administrator account.